# Extract coefficients of list of list of lme

Tags: r, list, nlme

I am struggling to get coefficients out of a list of list of several variables in linear mixed-effects model. I was looking for get the p-values of the interaction time:group, with a loop or sapply because I have 60 variables, and doing it individually is not an option

The general objective is to get the parameter I need but keeping the name of variable; meaning obtain a dataframe or matrix feasible to export.

I have tried to flat like I've done before with other list of list with do.call in combination with lapply, but I guess the format lme is somehow tricky, and I am not solving it

```
#1st try

dd <- lapply(sample, unlist)
do.call(rbind, lapply(dd, function(z)c(z, rep(NA, max-length(z)))))

#2nd try
result <- lapply(sample, function(x) summary(x)$tTable)
```

Thanks in advance

Edit 1: the library I am using is nlme with the function lme. I will post the steps taken till arrive the list of results. I am really having problems (singularity in backsolve error) running with a small database so I attach the database in https://pastebin.com/NnfHn0XZ

```
# names of variables

example.names <- colnames(example)[6:8] 
no.example <- length(example.names)

# create a named list to hold the fitted models
example.list <- as.list(1:no.example)
names(example.list) <- example.names


for(i in example.names){ 

  

# print status
  print(paste("Running entity:", i, "which is", which(example.names==i), "out of", no.example))
  
# trying to ignore variable because of few observations
  if(i == "abcg4")next
      print(i)

# create temporary data matrix and model formula
  tmp <- example[, c(i,"edad0","time", "grup_int", "id")]
  fml <- as.formula( paste( i, "~", paste(c("edad0","time", "grup_int", "time:grup_int"), collapse="+") ) )

  # assign fit to list by name
  example.list[[i]] <- lme(fml, random= ~ time|id, method="REML", data=tmp, na.action = na.omit)
  example.res <- print(summary(example.list[[i]]))

}
```

Right now you should obtain a nested list with 4 elemnts and many more (coefficients, dims, terms, call..)

```
example <- structure(list(id = structure(c(60901034, 50203013, 50203020, 
110113005, 140102090, 140103038, 70713001, 50203009, 50203026, 
110113003, 50203013, 140101099, 50203030, 60901021, 60901024, 
130102009, 71801001, 120715020, 50203026, 140102090, 140102095, 
110113003, 140102087, 140103035, 130105045, 111201006, 50203013, 
50203004, 140102087, 50203004, 60901020, 130108009, 140101091, 
120715021, 140102088, 70111024, 50203031, 140103035, 50202099, 
50109026, 50203030, 140103030, 70802013, 70713001, 110104019, 
60901031, 140101096, 140101096, 120715034, 140102088, 50203022, 
50508027, 120715033, 110113008, 50203009, 140101099, 110113001, 
130102010, 60901023, 110104017, 130108009, 60901033, 50202099, 
111201006, 50203026, 111201014, 140103028, 70111023, 110104019, 
50203014, 50109019, 140103033, 120715012, 120715035, 120715026, 
120715026, 120715033, 140103036, 50203027, 111202009, 60901023, 
140103028, 71801002, 120715033, 140103030, 120715030, 50203020, 
140102092, 70111023, 50203027, 140103033, 140103026, 130104004, 
50203019, 110104027, 120715027, 110606061, 110113007, 140103036, 
71801002, 60901031, 130102009, 140102088, 140101088, 120715033, 
70710002, 140102089, 110110005, 50203027, 120715035, 120715029, 
110606056, 140103038, 130102013, 130104004, 50203013, 70107034, 
110104028, 50109025, 60901028, 50109025, 120715026, 110606056, 
140103038, 50203016, 120715029, 60901026, 50203006, 110104030, 
50203030, 140103036, 110606061, 110113003, 110606061, 140103023, 
70107034, 60901028, 70710002, 111201007, 130108008, 60901034, 
50203032, 140103030, 60901023, 140103019, 50203029, 50203029, 
120715027, 70111021, 110113005, 60901027, 50203015, 50203014, 
50202099, 140102088, 111201017, 140103024, 130102013, 60901030, 
140102088, 140103033, 50521002, 111201006, 120715033, 110113003, 
70802015, 70802013, 111202015, 50203030, 70802015, 130104004, 
140103028, 60901038, 110113005, 120715012, 130102009, 110113007, 
110113006, 120715027, 140103024, 50203022, 60901031, 110104017, 
60901034, 70802015, 110104030, 50203006, 50203015, 50508026, 
110113003, 50203032, 140103020, 50109019, 120715037, 111201026, 
120715027, 50203014, 110110005, 70713001, 60901036, 60901035, 
70204056, 50203022, 140103033, 50203022, 110113008, 130108008, 
120715035, 120715034, 110113006, 50109025, 71801002, 70713001, 
130102009, 130104004, 130108009, 50203012, 110113003, 71801003, 
70111024, 120715026, 70201047, 111201026, 60901031, 130105044, 
110104019, 110606061, 50203013, 111201026, 110104029, 110606061, 
140102087, 120715035, 60901021, 70111021, 111201019, 50203017, 
50203010, 120715035, 50203017, 50203015, 71801001, 50203017, 
50521002, 70802012, 130102014, 110104029, 50601001, 120715033, 
110606056, 60901021, 120715021, 120715019, 60901037, 111201014, 
120715020, 140103038, 50203031, 130108008, 50508026, 71801001, 
60901034, 130105045, 70211014, 70802015, 140102090, 140103036, 
111201019, 110113008, 130106034, 50203012, 60901029, 60901028, 
50109025, 50527001, 60901037, 110113006, 111201006, 60901034, 
60901028, 50203004, 110113006, 130102008, 60901033, 60901038, 
110113006, 120715026, 130104004, 140103026, 60901026, 70713002, 
111201026, 50203017, 50109018, 140103030, 60901023, 111201026, 
140103028, 50508026, 70713002, 70713001, 120715033, 71801002, 
50203013, 71801003, 70802011, 111201007, 120715019, 50521001, 
50508027, 50109026, 70802015, 60901036, 111201007, 140101097, 
130105044, 110606061, 140101097, 110104028, 111201017, 140102087, 
60901023, 50203015, 50202099, 50203014, 50601001, 70710002, 60901031, 
50109027, 70802015, 50203015, 60901034, 50203031, 110606056, 
60901028, 130104004, 130106038, 50203031, 111201019, 60901026, 
60901021, 140103026, 60901027, 130106034, 120715026, 120715032, 
140101099, 70802015, 70111022, 50203027, 140101097, 140102089, 
60901024, 70802011, 50202099, 140103035, 120715020, 130102014, 
120715034, 120715027, 110113006, 50521002, 130108008, 111201007, 
120715035, 111202015, 50118001, 50109019, 60901036, 50508026, 
111201006, 110606056, 140102092, 140103027, 110606056, 71801001, 
130102012, 60901020, 70111023, 110104028, 60901035, 50527001, 
130102013, 50109025, 70111022, 140103020, 140101091, 111201007, 
120715030, 50109027, 50203016, 140102092, 60901036, 120715012, 
110606056, 110113007, 50203029, 140102092, 60901031, 50203016
), label = "Identificador", format.spss = "F10.0", display_width = 10L), 
    grup_int = structure(c(2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
    3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
    3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
    3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1), label = "GENERAL: Grupo de intervención", format.spss = "F2.0"), 
    sexo = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), label = "INCLUSIÓN: Sexo del participante", format.spss = "F2.0"), 
    edad0 = structure(c(60, 59, 64, 73, 80, 68, 76, 71, 60, 70, 
    59, 73, 65, 55, 58, 65, 66, 73, 60, 80, 61, 70, 64, 81, 57, 
    70, 59, 79, 64, 79, 66, 67, 55, 67, 60, 63, 59, 81, 78, 73, 
    65, 64, 61, 76, 60, 69, 73, 73, 68, 60, 60, 56, 68, 64, 71, 
    73, 66, 70, 64, 63, 67, 61, 78, 70, 60, 70, 77, 72, 60, 55, 
    80, 74, 64, 63, 68, 68, 68, 76, 64, 68, 64, 77, 80, 68, 64, 
    68, 64, 71, 72, 64, 74, 70, 72, 66, 62, 64, 64, 74, 76, 80, 
    69, 65, 60, 57, 68, 75, 62, 58, 64, 63, 67, 60, 68, 73, 72, 
    59, 60, 61, 76, 58, 76, 68, 60, 68, 73, 67, 75, 60, 72, 65, 
    76, 64, 70, 64, 68, 60, 58, 75, 70, 59, 60, 57, 64, 64, 62, 
    57, 57, 64, 71, 73, 66, 55, 55, 78, 60, 67, 59, 73, 71, 60, 
    74, 60, 70, 68, 70, 61, 61, 57, 65, 61, 72, 77, 68, 73, 64, 
    65, 74, 63, 64, 59, 60, 69, 63, 60, 61, 72, 60, 55, 74, 70, 
    57, 66, 80, 66, 62, 64, 55, 58, 76, 63, 75, 64, 60, 74, 60, 
    64, 59, 63, 68, 63, 76, 80, 76, 65, 72, 67, 61, 70, 73, 63, 
    68, 63, 62, 69, 59, 60, 64, 59, 62, 59, 64, 64, 63, 55, 71, 
    64, 74, 60, 63, 74, 55, 66, 74, 60, 60, 70, 59, 68, 68, 60, 
    55, 67, 70, 60, 70, 73, 68, 59, 59, 74, 66, 60, 57, 75, 61, 
    80, 76, 64, 64, 63, 61, 64, 58, 76, 65, 60, 63, 70, 60, 58, 
    79, 63, 70, 61, 68, 63, 68, 72, 70, 75, 62, 62, 74, 76, 64, 
    64, 62, 77, 74, 62, 76, 68, 80, 59, 73, 73, 70, 70, 62, 56, 
    73, 61, 63, 70, 71, 59, 64, 71, 61, 67, 64, 64, 55, 78, 55, 
    68, 75, 69, 61, 61, 55, 60, 59, 60, 58, 72, 70, 59, 64, 75, 
    55, 70, 66, 63, 68, 60, 73, 61, 69, 64, 71, 62, 58, 73, 78, 
    81, 73, 70, 68, 64, 63, 60, 59, 70, 63, 57, 60, 80, 63, 74, 
    70, 60, 71, 76, 60, 66, 75, 66, 72, 61, 75, 65, 73, 76, 69, 
    66, 55, 70, 68, 61, 73, 71, 63, 64, 60, 74, 57, 71, 69, 73
    ), label = "INCLUSIÓN: Edad en años en fecha de inclusión", format.spss = "F3.0"), 
    time = c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
    1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 
    3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
    3, 1, 1, 3), ppara = c(NA, 19.259, 21.317, 20.839, 21.253, 
    NA, 20.824, NA, 19.557, NA, 19.259, 20.015, 19.568, NA, 19.963, 
    18.838, 20.838, 18.795, 19.557, NA, 19.567, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    20.008, 19.259, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.532, NA, 21.625, 19.306, 
    19.8, NA, 18.703, NA, 19.587, 20.889, 20.76, 20.824, 18.669, 
    20.833, 18.863, 18.863, 20.256, 21.625, NA, 20.813, 20.014, 
    21.044, NA, 23.055, 19.968, 19.524, NA, 20.273, NA, 19.452, 
    18.703, 20.008, 19.557, 19.53, NA, 20.253, 18.669, 22.713, 
    19.822, NA, 18.802, 18.17, 20.159, 18.928, 20.014, NA, 20.332, 
    20.564, NA, 18.558, 20.369, 20.315, 20.889, 20.263, 21.317, 
    20.32, 20.253, 20.581, NA, 19.817, 21.732, 20.451, NA, 19.985, 
    19.797, 19.11, 20.07, 20.369, 20.921, 18.838, 21.258, 20.599, 
    20.014, 20.091, 19.518, 20.055, 20.581, 18.17, NA, 19.651, 
    NA, NA, 20.215, 19.259, NA, 19.242, 20.78, 20.251, 20.78, 
    18.928, 19.651, NA, NA, 19.421, NA, NA, 20.611, 19.568, 20.07, 
    19.715, NA, 19.797, NA, NA, 20.251, 20.091, 19.555, NA, NA, 
    19.94, NA, NA, 19.681, 18.832, 18.832, 20.032, 21.377, 20.839, 
    20.642, 22.463, 22.713, 19.093, 21.258, 19.568, 20.466, NA, 
    19.639, 21.625, 21.045, 19.758, 20.472, 20.014, NA, 20.799, 
    19.785, 19.608, 19.568, 20.799, 20.215, 18.558, 20.968, 20.965, 
    18.802, 18.805, 19.11, 19.331, 19.985, 21.133, NA, 20.921, 
    20.273, 19.575, 19.395, 20.611, NA, 19.82, 20.017, NA, 19.94, 
    19.16, 20.496, 19.24, 19.428, 20.032, 22.713, NA, 20.824, 
    18.725, NA, 22.983, NA, NA, NA, 21.044, 19.13, 18.17, 19.231, 
    19.331, 20.78, 18.837, 20.824, 18.838, 21.732, NA, 19.789, 
    NA, 21.81, 21.549, 18.928, 19.92, 19.428, 20.833, 19.427, 
    18.669, 19.797, 19.259, 19.428, 19.708, 19.797, NA, 18.17, 
    NA, 21.377, 20.584, 19.778, 20.191, 18.17, 19.778, 19.82, 
    20.838, 19.778, 19.758, 20.139, 18.534, 19.708, 20.424, 20.014, 
    20.357, NA, NA, 18.574, 21.621, 19.53, 18.795, NA, 20.345, 
    19.13, 20.017, 19.788, 19.575, NA, 18.887, 20.799, NA, 20.07, 
    20.584, 21.044, 22.092, 19.789, 19.82, 20.251, 20.78, 19.354, 
    20.213, 20.544, 20.008, 19.575, 20.455, 20.884, 20.544, 19.614, 
    19.452, 20.968, 19.331, 20.159, 21.732, 19.817, NA, 19.901, 
    19.428, 19.778, 18.281, 20.889, NA, 19.428, 18.558, 20.017, 
    19.901, 21.428, 20.014, 20.369, 19.259, 21.81, 20.922, 19.555, 
    18.574, 20.196, 21.576, 19.847, 20.799, 18.725, 19.555, 20.838, 
    19.427, 19.797, 20.838, 19.242, 19.568, NA, NA, 19.82, 18.703, 
    20.075, 20.424, 20.807, 20.921, NA, 20.799, 19.82, NA, 20.345, 
    20.357, 20.251, 21.732, 21.047, 20.345, 19.913, 18.802, NA, 
    19.817, 20.642, 22.092, 18.928, 20.335, 23.055, 20.799, NA, 
    20.581, 19.999, 19.518, 19.715, 20.922, 18.703, NA, 19.719, 
    20.409, 20.256, 20.032, 19.331, 19.758, NA, 19.884, 19.842, 
    19.608, NA, 20.496, 18.725, 20.017, 20.008, 20.357, 20.32, 
    20.228, 20.357, 19.788, NA, NA, 20.253, 19.242, NA, 19.354, 
    NA, 20.78, NA, 19.16, 20.532, 19.884, 20.208, NA, NA, 20.235, 
    18.725, 18.802, 20.357, 20.679, 18.832, 20.235, 20.833, NA
    ), nr1h2 = c(18.729, 17.754, 19.515, 18.669, 20.194, 16.586, 
    18.554, 18.238, 18.621, 17.641, 17.754, 18.509, 18.646, 19.29, 
    18.503, 17.488, 19.548, 17.634, 18.621, 18.753, 17.54, 17.641, 
    18.271, 18.156, 16.974, 17.584, 17.754, 20.274, 18.381, 20.274, 
    18.315, 17.601, 19.47, 18.074, 19.229, 17.228, 18.762, 16.953, 
    17.718, 18.88, 18.562, 18.652, 18.929, 18.554, 17.454, 19.595, 
    18.225, 18.225, 18.52, 19.229, 19.211, 18.049, 18.23, 18.953, 
    18.238, 21.265, 18.163, 17.836, 18.637, 18.975, 17.601, 17.954, 
    17.718, 17.584, 18.621, 18.395, 18.832, 18.844, 17.454, 20.567, 
    18.37, 18.203, 17.258, 16.875, 17.995, 16.683, 18.23, 17.804, 
    17.931, 17.892, 18.89, 16.677, 18.767, 18.616, 18.652, 18.427, 
    19.515, 17.848, 18.844, 18.568, 18.203, 16.63, 19.178, 18.803, 
    16.588, 17.361, 18.19, 17.17, 17.826, 18.767, 18.839, 17.488, 
    19.078, 18.323, 18.23, 18.011, 17.392, 18.75, 18.568, 16.875, 
    18.793, 18.242, 16.586, 18.106, 18.534, 17.754, 18.458, 17.126, 
    19.287, 18.754, 19.287, 16.683, 18.242, 16.586, 18.494, 17.36, 
    17.891, 17.755, 15.292, 18.646, 17.826, 18.091, 17.641, 18.19, 
    19.196, 18.458, 18.754, 18.011, 17.647, 17.88, 18.729, 18.424, 
    NA, 18.637, 17.605, 17.472, 17.472, 17.615, 19.729, 18.669, 
    18.703, 20.759, 20.567, 18.531, 19.078, 17.172, 17.163, 18.106, 
    17.583, 19.229, 18.859, 18.449, 18.273, 18.23, 17.641, 19.295, 
    18.591, 18.137, 18.646, 19.295, 18.534, 16.677, 18.947, 18.517, 
    17.258, 17.217, 17.17, 17.322, 17.361, 18.801, 18.152, 18.839, 
    18.975, 17.815, 18.738, 15.292, 17.755, 18.266, 18.586, 17.641, 
    18.424, 17.661, 18.593, 17.347, 17.715, 17.615, 20.567, 17.985, 
    18.554, 18.22, 19.118, 20.694, 18.152, 18.203, 18.152, 18.953, 
    17.651, 16.875, 16.795, 17.322, 19.287, 18.207, 18.554, 17.488, 
    19.178, 17.601, 17.767, 17.641, 19.525, 19.048, 16.683, 18.233, 
    17.715, 19.595, 17.513, 17.454, 18.19, 17.754, 17.715, 17.196, 
    18.19, 18.381, 16.875, 19.29, 19.729, 18.782, 18.473, 19.536, 
    16.875, 18.473, 18.266, 19.548, 18.473, 18.449, 17.991, 17.307, 
    17.196, 18.827, 18.23, 18.176, 18.407, 18.074, 16.786, 19.803, 
    18.395, 17.634, 16.586, 19.265, 17.651, 18.586, 18.476, 17.815, 
    16.974, 17.999, 19.295, 18.753, 17.826, 18.782, 18.953, 19.355, 
    17.767, 18.789, 18.754, 19.287, 17.615, 19.015, 18.367, 17.584, 
    17.815, 19.514, 18.775, 18.367, 17.713, 17.954, 18.947, 17.322, 
    17.995, 19.178, 16.63, 17.891, 18.792, 17.715, 18.473, 18.17, 
    18.652, 18.89, 17.715, 16.677, 18.586, 18.792, 19.367, 18.23, 
    18.767, 17.754, 19.525, 18.202, 17.647, 16.786, 18.753, 20.237, 
    18.418, 19.295, 18.22, 17.647, 18.757, 17.513, 18.19, 18.757, 
    17.126, 17.172, 18.271, 18.637, 18.266, 17.718, 18.6, 18.827, 
    18.314, 18.839, 18.728, 19.295, 18.266, 18.729, 19.265, 18.176, 
    18.754, 19.178, 20.002, 19.265, 18.836, 18.529, 19.29, 16.63, 
    18.703, 19.355, 16.683, 17.784, 21.265, 19.295, 19.221, 18.568, 
    18.532, 17.392, 18.635, 18.202, 17.718, 16.953, 17.86, 18.307, 
    18.52, 17.615, 17.322, 18.449, 17.88, 18.242, 17.651, 18.137, 
    18.325, 18.593, 18.22, 18.586, 17.584, 18.176, 17.848, 17.815, 
    18.176, 18.476, 17.954, 18.315, 18.844, 17.126, 19.061, 17.615, 
    18.106, 19.287, 19.221, 17.661, 19.47, 18.242, 17.276, 18.728, 
    18.494, 18.073, 18.22, 17.258, 18.176, 18.217, 17.472, 18.073, 
    19.595, 18.494), nr1h3 = c(21.805, 21.047, 22.814, 22.091, 
    23.366, 19.842, 22.68, 21.526, 22.031, NA, 21.047, 21.794, 
    21.197, 22.599, 21.943, 20.931, 22.845, 21.254, 22.031, 22.4, 
    20.677, NA, 21.82, 21.838, 20.768, NA, 21.047, 23.672, 21.722, 
    23.672, 21.958, 21.2, 22.861, 20.831, 23.248, 20.216, 21.794, 
    20.622, 21.761, 22.613, 22.065, 22.045, 22.766, 22.68, 20.7, 
    22.988, 21.799, 21.799, 21.869, 23.248, 22.294, 22.346, 21.726, 
    21.792, 21.526, 24.441, 20.889, 21.255, 22.333, 22.187, 21.2, 
    21.173, 21.761, NA, 22.031, 21.045, 22.174, 22.538, 20.7, 
    24.801, 21.822, 21.807, 20.577, 19.989, 21.806, 20.192, 21.726, 
    20.37, 21.801, 21.218, 22.789, 20.462, 22.219, 21.676, 22.045, 
    21.761, 22.814, 21.175, 22.538, 22.238, 21.807, 20.679, 22.461, 
    21.828, 20.757, 21.168, 21.527, 20.621, 21.482, 22.219, 22.78, 
    20.931, 22.504, 21.923, 21.726, 21.761, 21.304, 21.426, 22.238, 
    19.989, 22.231, 20.641, 19.842, 21.405, 21.622, 21.047, NA, 
    21.11, 22.653, 22.019, 22.653, 20.192, 20.641, 19.842, 22.078, 
    21.151, 21.637, 21.285, 18.945, 21.197, 21.482, 21.832, NA, 
    21.527, 22.284, NA, 22.019, 21.761, NA, 21.698, 21.805, 22.065, 
    19.59, 22.333, 21.407, 21.064, 21.064, 21.37, 22.766, 22.091, 
    21.868, 23.322, 24.801, 22.507, 22.504, 21.227, 21.727, 21.405, 
    21.189, 23.248, 22.799, 21.858, 21.733, 21.726, NA, 22.797, 
    NA, 21.011, 21.197, 22.797, 21.622, 20.462, 22.404, 22.111, 
    20.577, NA, 20.621, 21.107, 21.168, 22.727, 21.36, 22.78, 
    22.187, 20.996, 21.915, 18.945, 21.285, 21.313, 21.886, NA, 
    22.065, 21.504, 22.31, 21.049, 20.133, 21.37, 24.801, NA, 
    22.68, 21.345, 22.648, 24.848, 21.36, 21.807, 21.36, 21.792, 
    21.177, 19.989, 20.836, 21.107, 22.653, 20.838, 22.68, 20.931, 
    22.461, 21.2, 20.808, NA, 23.581, 22.574, 20.192, 21.678, 
    20.133, 22.988, 21.326, 20.7, 21.527, 21.047, 20.133, 19.826, 
    21.527, 21.722, 19.989, 22.599, 22.766, 22.325, 22.121, 23.506, 
    19.989, 22.121, 21.313, 22.845, 22.121, 21.858, 21.804, 20.348, 
    19.826, 22.619, 21.726, 21.158, 21.556, 20.831, 20.591, 23.703, 
    21.045, 21.254, 19.842, 22.83, 21.177, 21.886, 22.409, 20.996, 
    20.768, 21.625, 22.797, 22.4, 21.482, 22.325, 21.792, 23.832, 
    20.808, 21.633, 22.019, 22.653, 21.544, 21.782, 21.664, NA, 
    20.996, 23.225, 22.33, 21.664, 21.582, 21.173, 22.404, 21.107, 
    21.806, 22.461, 20.679, 21.637, 22.155, 20.133, 22.121, 20.987, 
    22.045, 22.789, 20.133, 20.462, 21.886, 22.155, 23.02, 21.726, 
    22.219, 21.047, 23.581, 22.478, NA, 20.591, 22.007, 24.263, 
    23.112, 22.797, 21.345, NA, 22.077, 21.326, 21.527, 22.077, 
    21.11, 21.227, 21.82, 22.333, 21.313, 21.761, 21.898, 22.619, 
    21.71, 22.78, 22.59, 22.797, 21.313, 21.805, 22.83, 21.158, 
    22.019, 22.461, 23.269, 22.83, NA, 21.894, 22.599, 20.679, 
    21.868, 23.832, 20.192, 21.432, 24.441, 22.797, 22.769, 22.238, 
    21.933, 21.304, 22.196, 22.478, 21.761, 20.622, 21.912, 21.922, 
    21.869, 21.37, 21.107, 21.858, 21.698, 21.413, 20.685, 21.011, 
    21.808, 22.31, 21.345, 21.886, NA, 21.158, 21.175, 21.834, 
    21.158, 22.409, 21.722, 21.958, 22.538, 21.11, 22.191, 21.544, 
    21.405, 22.653, 22.769, 21.504, 22.861, 21.413, 21.569, 22.59, 
    22.078, 21.325, 21.345, 20.577, 21.158, 22.169, 21.064, 21.325, 
    22.988, 22.078), rxra = c(14.288, 13.771, 15.656, 14.278, 
    15.823, 12.512, 13.828, 14.393, 15.366, 12.92, 13.771, 14.633, 
    14.818, 14.666, 13.738, 12.737, 14.764, 13.247, 15.366, 14.79, 
    13.567, 12.92, 14.335, 14.005, 12.796, 13.457, 13.771, 16.464, 
    14.694, 16.464, 14.514, 13.359, 14.693, 14.142, 15.81, 13.224, 
    14.765, 12.631, 13.959, 14.513, 15.591, 13.873, 14.805, 13.828, 
    13.255, 14.864, 14.047, 14.047, 14.623, 15.81, 15.334, 13.96, 
    13.791, 14.609, 14.393, 17.165, 13.605, 12.874, 14.999, 15.175, 
    13.359, 13.742, 13.959, 13.457, 15.366, 14.324, NA, 14.699, 
    13.255, 16.553, 14.081, 14.142, 12.816, 12.477, 13.748, 12.647, 
    13.791, NA, 14.521, 13.293, 14.739, 12.447, 14.165, 14.022, 
    13.873, 14.312, 15.656, 13.142, 14.699, 14.059, 14.142, 12.531, 
    14.024, 14.438, 12.906, 12.895, 14.033, 12.82, 13.968, 14.165, 
    14.732, 12.737, 14.533, 13.991, 13.791, 13.65, 13.293, 14.813, 
    14.059, 12.477, 14.736, NA, 12.512, 14.42, 13.802, 13.771, 
    14.836, 13.42, 14.837, 14.293, 14.837, 12.647, NA, 12.512, 
    14.742, 13.272, 14.129, 13.471, 12.766, 14.818, 13.968, 13.743, 
    12.92, 14.033, 15.086, 14.836, 14.293, 13.65, 13.023, 13.811, 
    14.288, 14.599, NA, 14.999, 13.444, 13.1, 13.1, 13.328, 15.327, 
    14.278, 14.663, 16.294, 16.553, 14.61, 14.533, 13.063, 13.483, 
    14.42, 13.388, 15.81, 14.786, 14.722, 14.551, 13.791, 12.92, 
    14.954, 14.568, 14.152, 14.818, 14.954, 13.802, 12.447, 14.58, 
    14.004, 12.816, 13.036, 12.82, 13.379, 12.895, 14.631, 14.378, 
    14.732, 15.175, 13.762, 14.596, 12.766, 13.471, 13.974, 14.368, 
    12.92, 14.599, 13.167, 14.75, 12.849, 12.829, 13.328, 16.553, 
    14.302, 13.828, 13.695, 14.313, 16.185, 14.378, 14.142, 14.378, 
    14.609, 12.816, 12.477, 12.865, 13.379, 14.837, NA, 13.828, 
    12.737, 14.024, 13.359, 14.423, 12.92, 15.385, 14.463, 12.647, 
    13.827, 12.829, 14.864, 13.55, 13.255, 14.033, 13.771, 12.829, 
    12.835, 14.033, 14.694, 12.477, 14.666, 15.327, 14.685, 14.524, 
    15.331, 12.477, 14.524, 13.974, 14.764, 14.524, 14.722, 13.317, 
    12.725, 12.835, 15.237, 13.791, 14.275, 13.943, 14.142, 12.809, 
    15.592, 14.324, 13.247, 12.512, 15.273, 12.816, 14.368, 13.817, 
    13.762, 12.796, 13.711, 14.954, 14.79, 13.968, 14.685, 14.609, 
    14.448, 14.423, 14.498, 14.293, 14.837, 13.92, 14.957, 14.663, 
    13.457, 13.762, 14.776, 15.165, 14.663, 13.622, 13.742, 14.58, 
    13.379, 13.748, 14.024, 12.531, 14.129, 14.586, 12.829, 14.524, 
    13.827, 13.873, 14.739, 12.829, 12.447, 14.368, 14.586, 14.822, 
    13.791, 14.165, 13.771, 15.385, 13.829, 13.023, 12.809, 15.549, 
    16.619, 14.784, 14.954, 13.695, 13.023, 14.721, 13.55, 14.033, 
    14.721, 13.42, 13.063, 14.335, 14.999, 13.974, 13.959, 14.084, 
    15.237, 14.592, 14.732, 14.401, 14.954, 13.974, 14.288, 15.273, 
    14.275, 14.293, 14.024, 15.704, 15.273, NA, 13.866, 14.666, 
    12.531, 14.663, 14.448, 12.647, 13.175, 17.165, 14.954, 15.08, 
    14.059, 14, 13.293, 14.602, 13.829, 13.959, 12.631, 14.042, 
    14.389, 14.623, 13.328, 13.379, 14.722, 13.811, 13.761, 13.513, 
    14.152, 14.123, 14.75, 13.695, 14.368, 13.457, 14.275, 13.142, 
    12.938, 14.275, 13.817, 13.657, 14.514, 14.699, 13.42, 14.581, 
    13.92, 14.42, 14.837, 15.08, 13.167, 14.693, 13.761, 13.471, 
    14.401, 14.742, 13.765, 13.695, 12.816, 14.275, 13.388, 13.1, 
    13.765, 14.864, 14.742)), row.names = c(NA, -400L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you show the code that you use to do the calibration? Which library are you using to calibrate the linear mixed effect model?

Comment: Edit 1 with df attached in URL because of the length

Comment: Could you run the code with the edition?

Comment: Could you show how you load the data in R? Do you do some data manipulation after loading the data in R?

Comment: This is a database for carry out the example. My original data is .sav format so:

Comment: This is a database to carry out the example, I do manipulate my data. My original data is .sav format so:

``` dat <- read_sav("G:/Otros ordenadores/PC1/Beca Río Hortega/OpenArray/A25/BBDD/predB50_A25.sav")
dat <- as.data.frame(dat) 
genes <- dat %>% dplyr::select(c("id", "sample_name", "experiment_name", "sexo", "edad0", "grup_int", "peso1", "imc1", "cint1", "cadera1", 482:593, "endogenous_ct_01", "endogenous_ct_03")) %>% pivot_longer(cols = matches("crt_"), names_to = c("gen", "time"), names_sep = "_0",values_to = "value") 
```

Comment: genes$gen <- str_remove(genes$gen, pattern = "crt_")
genes <- base::as.data.frame(genes)
genes<- genes %>% pivot_wider(names_from = gen)

genes$time [genes$time == "1"] <- 1 
genes$time [genes$time == "2"] <- 2 
genes$time [genes$time == "3"] <- 3 

genes$time<-as.numeric(genes$time)

After this manipulation of the data, I selected from the dataframe several variables ( 2 or 3 ) to make up the example dataframe. The syntaxis work till get the list of list. I have done lme models before but not in a loop resulting in nested lists. Thank you

Comment: To help you, I need to be able to replicate your results and run your code. At the moment, I am not able.

Comment: I have pasted a dataframe example to run it. I don't understand why I wasn't able to paste it first place. 
The syntax pasted in comments is just informative, no need to run to obtain the list of results